# How to turn off audio from a video using AVAudioPlayer?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, avaudioplayer

I have a simple camera that records a video then transitions to a videoPreview. In it there is a button that hwne presses segues back to the camera. However hwen I do this the video audio does not stop. How can I delete it (not mute) so that a new vid can be taken?

Bellow is my Video preview code with what I have attempted

```
    class VideoPlayback: UIViewController {

    //receives url video value from VideoViewController
    var videoURL: URL!

    //place where video gets displayed
    @IBOutlet weak var videoView: UIView!

    var avPlayer = AVPlayer()

    private var playerQueue: AVQueuePlayer!
    private var playerItem1: AVPlayerItem!
    private var playerLooper: AVPlayerLooper!
    private var playerLayer: AVPlayerLayer!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        print(avPlayer, "avPlayer")
        print("videoURL", videoURL)

        playerItem1 = AVPlayerItem(url: videoURL as URL)
        print(playerItem1, "playerItem1")

        playerQueue = AVQueuePlayer(playerItem: playerItem1)
        print(playerQueue, "player queue")

        playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: playerQueue)
        print(playerLayer, "playerLayer")

        playerLooper = AVPlayerLooper(player: playerQueue, templateItem: playerItem1)
        print(playerLooper, "player looper")

        playerLayer.frame = view.bounds
        playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
        print(videoView, "yruewioq")
        videoView.layer.insertSublayer(playerLayer, at: 0)

        view.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.playerQueue?.play()
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        //attempt at turing audio off
        playerQueue = nil
    }
    @IBAction func cancelVidPreviewButton(_ sender: Any) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "cancelVideo", sender: self)
    }
}
```

**Update:**

I have also tried `playerLayer.isMuted = true`
 But I get that it has no member isMuted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I see that actually what needs to be done here is all the video data which has audio needs to be removed as seen bellow

```
        self.playerQueue?.removeAllItems()
```

But if you want to get rid of audio you just need to do `.pause()` and then remove the data.  here is [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer)

Comment: there is no `stop` method in `AVPlayer`

Comment: i know about the `pause` method, but there is no `stop` method there, as you previously stated `stop` instead of `pause`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you need to make sure audio session has ended before segue. Setting volume to zero might affect audio session though.

Comment: I am not trying to mut but delleted completely So that hwen a new vid is made the sounds dont overlap

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `AVPlayer's` `volume` property to control the volume of AVPlayer.

Setting `volume` to `0` can mute the audio.

According to the [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer/1390127-volume):

> A value of 0.0 indicates silence; a value of 1.0 (the default)
>   indicates full audio volume for the player instance.

Hope this helps

Comment: I am not trying to mut but delleted completely So that hwen a new vid is made the sounds dont overlap